# How would you use this space?

Tags: attic, architecture

I recently purchased a condo and there is a loft area above a room that you can see in the picture. please don't tell me to use it as a storage! aha
i wonder if anyone has a creative idea of how to use the space. it fits a bed (already tried to sleep there but the height is barely 4 feet. are is about 7x8 feet

[image]

Comment: Small library with reading nook.

Answer (score 2):

**Beanbag TV lounge.**

[image: beanbag lounge]

Beanbags will fit.  You can watch movies or play video games in there.